# iOS6: duplicate symbol error in xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ios6

I am having a problem running my application.

I am receiving a build failed due to duplicate symbol.

[image]

I am including a **`magtek idynamo`** sdk to my application. On my previous app version usually I am adding the libMTSCRA.a to the libraries and the MTSCRA.h to my project. Based on my research people suggested that the problem occurs because I am referencing the .h and also the .a which I've managed to work on ios5 version of my app. Its frustrating.. I've been banging my head against the wall on this one.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
[image]
Here is the screenshot of my framework and libraries. libMTSCRA.a is only listed once.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems fine so far. So it did work with previous compiler and iOS versions?

Comment: What does your complete "Other Linker Flags" setting look like for the target? If it contains `-lMTSCRA` the linker would link the library twice.

Comment: -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-ISystem

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too, and after many time, I can solve it by removing the other linker flag => "-all_load"

Due to this flag, the 2 libraries (iphoneos and iphonesimulator) of MagTek were included at the same time.

Comment: This answer worked for me although Im using Cordova/Phonegap which requires `-all_load`. So instead I used `-force_load` linker flag on libCordova.a and could remove `-all_load`. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't have anything to do with the header files. Instead, it indicates that the listed function **bodies** (usually in the .m, but a part of the static library if you're built them into a static library) are being included twice.

Most likely, you're including the static library twice. It may be that one of those inclusions is indirect; you're including another static library that's also including the static library.

Comment: sorry for being so dumb but what should i do again? i'm relatively new to objective c. my application is phonegap based so i'm not really diving into objective xcode most of the time.

Comment: Select on your project in the left panel, select your target in the middle panel and look under 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'. Check that libMTSCRA.a isn't listed twice. If it is only in there once try removing it and see if your project builds.

Comment: i updated the question. posted is the screenshot of my framework and libraries. libMTSCRA.a is only listed once.

Comment: That's the easy part. The hard part: any of those other libraries *also* include it?

Comment: as far as i know, no. libc++.dylib and external accessory are also needed inorder for libMTSCRA.a to work

Comment: @StevenFisher - if the header file contains non-inline function definitions (bad design, anyway), then this can be related to header files. Also, this appears to be C++ code rather than Objective-C.

Comment: That's true. Those functions should be static at a minimum (so every compilation unit gets its own copy, with hashed naming) and that'd still be strange code.

Comment: Have you implemented the magtek idynamo sdk? I'm coding using Phonegap so I can't really figure out which library is causing this. I'm in contact with magtek and they said that their library has nothing to do with the error.