# Apple Mach-O Linker - Ignoring file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

This might be a stupid question but I would like to ask if xcode shows a warning saying

```
ignoring file /filepath, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked(armv7)
```

Does it mean that xcode actually skips the file when building the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It means that GCC or Clang (or rather the linker invoked by them) skips the file when building the project.

Comment: just like what I said then? ->  Does it mean that xcode actually skips the file when building the project?

Comment: @Dreyfus15 No, it's not Xcode, it's the linker. Xcode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Dreyfus15 No problem :) I'm glad I could help. Also, it might be useful for you to know that the reason is that you're building for some other architecture than ARMv7 (i. e. i386 in case of the iPhone simulator or ARMv6 for older devices) - you can fix this by supplying a library or object file with the correct, ARMv7 architecture.

Comment: thanks, hey. would you happen to know how to fix duplicate symbols?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738435/ios6-duplicate-symbol-error-in-xcode-4-5

Comment: @Dreyfus15 I'll have a look at that also.