# Cordova 2.1.0 magtek idynamo sdk

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios6

We upgraded our cordova from 1.6.1 to 2.1.0 and also to iOS6. Now we are experiencing duplicate symbol error. here is the link of my question [iOS6: duplicate symbol error in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738435/ios6-duplicate-symbol-error-in-xcode-4-5)

I tried downgrading cordova. On 2.0.0 still have the same problem but when I downgraded to 1.9.0 it works fine. Based on my initial research I found out that the problem might be caused by the new Xcode project template of cordova. Since 1.6.1 to 1.9.0, creating a new project must be done from the xcode application but with 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 the project is created via command line. Can anybody help me shed some light with this? Thank you

Comment: Did you ever get the issue figured out?  I'm about to start looking into PhoneGap + MagTek integration... was wondering if you were able to make something happen?